# Washing machine agitator not turning

Tags: washing-machine

The agitator barrel is not snapping into the agitator base. Hence it is not turning. How do I get the agitator barrel to snap into the agitator base. Whirlpool Washer LSQ8000LQ1

Answer (score 1):

after reading a ton of threads on agitators, watching videos, and speaking with livesupport and appliance repair people, i verified that the 7/16" agitator hold down bolt  holds the upper agitator onto the lower agitator.

i removed the bolt from the lower agitator and didn't find any washers.  i found something resembling a metal washer so i put a rubber washer then the metal washer over it.  i put the cam kit on top then put the bolt back in and it held the upper agitator on the lower agitator.    the washing machine works again!